# Google Cloudprint setting papersize

Tags: php, printing, google-cloud-print

I run a script in where i'm sending pictures to a Google Cloudprinter;

```
$url = "https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit?printerid=". $this->_printerId."&output=json";

  $post = array(
      "printerid" => $this->_printerId,
      "capabilities" => "",
      "contentType" => "dataUrl",
      "title" => $title,
      "content" => 'data:application/pdf;base64,'. base64_encode($docBytes)
  );
```

The handling works, with authenticated CURL.
But i'm really stuck at setting the papersize.

I want to print A6 pictures, and it seems only to send A4. I cant find any info in the documentation about setting papersize, any help?

Comment: Make sure the pdf you are sending is A6, part of a PDF's makeup is the paper size.

Comment: i am sending a JPG. converting to PDF might be a bit too much

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the paper size you need to check which paper sizes the printer supports. You can do this by looking up the printer's capabilities https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/appInterfaces#printer (make sure to set use_cdd=true). Then you can find the media sizes that are supported by that printer. Pick one and create a print ticket (See "ticket" parameter of https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/appInterfaces#submit).

If you're always printing to the same printer, then you should be able to create the ticket once, and just hardcode it in your submission client.